# Why does a stored procedure run faster with "WITH RECOMPILE" even after it was just recompiled?

Tags: query-optimization, sql-server-2014

I had a stored procedure that took 40 seconds to run. So I ran

```
exec myproc WITH RECOMPILE
```

and it took less than a second. I tried running `exec myproc` directly after that and it took 2 seconds. I ran it several times like this and it consistently took 2 seconds. I then added `WITH RECOMPILE` back into my query and it once again took under a second to run.

I ran the stored procedure with the exact same parameters every time. I would think that, after having used `WITH RECOMPILE` the first time, it would just use the plan that was just created for subsequent runs that did not specify `WITH RECOMPILE`. If that assumption is correct, then it would seem like it takes longer to look up the execution plan that it does to just create a new one from scratch.

So what's really going on here?

EDIT: I would still love to know the answer to my question, which was how running the statement with the hint could possibly be faster than running it without the hint. But I took Aaron's advice and switched to using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on the select statement and it runs even faster so that's clearly my best option.

Comment: I would never use WITH RECOMPILE on the procedure definition or the call. Is there a statement in the procedure that benefits from a recompile? Why? Can that be fixed? If not, add OPTION (RECOMPILE) to that statement. [Please read this post in full](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I originally ran it as an adhoc statement to test whether it was the issue. I could have run sp_recompile, but I assume this is effectively the same. I then ran it again without `WITH RECOMPILE` and it was just strange to me that it was slower without it than with it. So I'm really just trying to understand how that is even possible. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AaronBertrand From the article `Using WITH RECOMPILE also means the compiled plan for the stored procedure is not cached.` Yet after having run the statement with this hint it, it then ran much faster afterward without the hint. So it sure seems like it does cache the plan. Very confusing. I can certainly see the downside of using WITH RECOMPILE if it doesn't store stats though.

Comment: I should also mention, for context, that in my case the proc only had one select statement.

Comment: I suspect there is more than one copy of the inner select in the plan cache, but I have no idea, really. Did you generate execution plans for each case and compare them?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Estimated plans looked identical at a glance... but perhaps I looked too quickly so I may check it out again. Thanks for all your input.

Comment: Generate real plans with perf metrics from SentryOne Plan Explorer. Estimated plans are garbage no matter where you look at them. Also running the procedure with recompile and then not, and the second execution being faster, does in no way mean it was faster because it benefitted from caching. There are lots and lots and lots of reasons why a different plan will be slower or faster, with compile time very rarely being relevant (maybe in the case where your query has 80 joins or pulls from a cascade of 30 views).

Comment: `how running the statement with the hint could possibly be faster than running it without the hint.` > sadly, we can't answer that without a lot more specifics.

Comment: It's not hard to write queries that can have drastically different plans based on their input parameters. Reusing a cached query plan can, for queries like that, can make things quite inefficient. When the offending query is embedded in stored code, `WITH RECOMPILE` on that stored code forces generation of a new plan.  My point? It's tough to answer "why?" questions about this without knowing  what's in your stored code.